# Number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length - Datacamp

Tags: r, ggplot2

I follow some classes in DataCamp about R and sometimes when I replicate the code from datacamp to R-studio, I have issues but usually, I find the answer here or generally online. However, this time I cannot understand what is the mistake or how to fix it. I copy paste the code from datacamp

```
# Compute cross-validated errors for up to 8 steps ahead

e <- matrix(NA_real_, nrow = 1000, ncol = 8)
for(h in 1:8)
  e[, h] <- tsCV(goog, forecastfunction = naive, h = h)

# Compute the MSE values and remove missing values

mse <- colMeans(e^2, na.rm = TRUE)

# Plot the MSE values against the forecast horizon

data.frame(h = 1:8, MSE = mse) %>%   ggplot(aes(x = h, y = MSE)) + geom_point()
```

When I add this code to R-studio (including the demanded packages) I always get the following error:

```
**Error in e[, h] <- tsCV(goog, forecastfunction = naive, h = h) : 
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length**
```

Does anybody know why does this happen?

Comment: Where does the `tsCV` function come from? Sounds like it's returning something other than 1000 values.

Comment: @MrFlick, the `forecast` package contains this function. In theory, according to the online running code on Datacamp this is OK, because there this code runs with no issues. However, here this doesn't seem to work. Specifically, instead of returning 8 values, it returns only 1. Generally, I just recently have started courses in Datacamp, thus, I do not really know if I have answered your question. Thank you again!

Comment: What is `goog`? Does it have 1000 values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is when h=1 the tsCV will return only one column when h=2 it will provide two columns h=1 and h=2 similarly if h=8 it will return 8 columns h=1,...h=8.  The following code will solve the problem but we will not be able to find values for h=1 with the loop (because `tsCV(goog, forecastfunction = naive, h = 1)` will be a vector and `[,1]` will be `an incorrect number of dimensions`) so we will calculate it separately:

```
library(forecast)
library(fpp2)


e <- matrix(data = NA, nrow = 1000, ncol =8)
for(h in 2:8){


  e[, h] <- tsCV(goog, forecastfunction = naive, h = h)[,h]
  }


e[,1]<- tsCV(goog, forecastfunction = naive, h = 1)                                          

# Compute the MSE values and remove missing values

mse <- colMeans(e^2, na.rm = TRUE)

# Plot the MSE values against the forecast horizon

data.frame(h = 1:8, MSE = mse) %>%   ggplot(aes(x = h, y = MSE)) + geom_point()
```

note that:
`tsCV` stands for Time series cross-validation from `forecast` package

`goog` is a data set from `fpp2` package

Comment: Dear @Akai, thank you very much for your response. The code you gave works perfectly, although I did not really understand what has happened. However, even the original code from datacamp I was not in position to understand, since the first part with the problem was written by them (which means that they would explain in some later class). Nevertheless, I still do not get why that code works in their online compiler! Thank you again for your help. I will close the query since your answer works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

when you set tsCV(h = n), it is returns n columns and calculate all values 1:n.
You can simply change your code to

```
# Compute cross-validated errors for up to 8 steps ahead
e <- matrix(NA_real_, nrow = 1000, ncol = 8)
e <- tsCV(goog, forecastfunction = naive, h = 8)

# Compute the MSE values and remove missing values
mse <- colMeans(e^2, na.rm = TRUE)

# Plot the MSE values against the forecast horizon
data.frame(h = 1:8, MSE = mse) %>%
ggplot(aes(x = h, y = MSE)) + geom_point()
```

If you want to know more about the tsCV function, below is the function code

```
function (y, forecastfunction, h = 1, window = NULL, ...) 
{
    y <- as.ts(y)
    n <- length(y)
    e <- ts(matrix(NA_real_, nrow = n, ncol = h))
    tsp(e) <- tsp(y)
    for (i in seq_len(n - 1)) {
        fc <- try(suppressWarnings(forecastfunction(subset(y, 
            start = ifelse(is.null(window), 1L, ifelse(i - window >= 
                0L, i - window + 1L, stop("small window"))), 
            end = i), h = h, ...)), silent = TRUE)
        if (!is.element("try-error", class(fc))) {
            e[i, ] <- y[i + (1:h)] - fc$mean
        }
    }
    if (h == 1) {
        return(e[, 1L])
    }
    else {
        colnames(e) <- paste("h=", 1:h, sep = "")
        return(e)
    }
}
<bytecode: 0x10e17fe70>
<environment: namespace:forecast>
```